# My app compatible with 0 devices (Android)

Tags: android, compatibility

My app is not visible on any mobile device. Installs with no problem from the APK file, works good, but for some reason, Google Play doesn't list it.

When I look at google play of the computer the error is: This app is not compatible with your device.

When I look at Google Play Console - device catalog, the compatible devices is 0.

Any suggestions for this?

**The app's manifest:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="br.com.tecmafandroid.projeto.tecmaf">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
            android:required="true" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_tecmaf"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_tecmaf_round"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

...
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

**build.gradle(app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.XXXandroid.projeto.XXX"
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2  subindo novas versões
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //dependencias firebase
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.rtoshiro.mflibrary:mflibrary:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
        android:required="true" />
```

It will be listed for device which only has Camera 2

In order to list for all devices,
make the `android:required = "false"` and handle for the devices which doesnt have Camera 2.

Comment: Thanks, but s that the only problem?

Comment: Yeah seems like it. You can actually remove that uses-feature tag `android.hardware.camera2` as such is not a feature

Comment: Make sure you handle for devices which doesnt support Camera2 API